# Copying data from one spreadsheet and inserting into another, using VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net

Basically I have a 'Mastersheet' that gets updated weekly and I want to capture the current data into an 'Individual worksheets'.

I need to iterate through my 'Mastersheet' then INSERT my data into the 'Individual sheets' based on the key name in column Foodtype. I.e. Apple data goes to Apple worksheet.

A few arguments: sorry if I sound repetitive

The column names are identical across each worksheet.

Data from Master spreadsheet may contain NULL cells, Foodtype data is absolute and never change or NULL.

I'm comfortable using OleDb connection method or Excel Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel - Although I prefer treating the Excel as a dataset so OleDB is favorable.

My current connection:

```
 Private Const connstring As String = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source =C:\Temp\Mainsheet.xlsx;extended properties=excel 8.0;"
```

Thanks-  enjoy the upcoming holidays.

**Mastersheet**

[image: Mastersheet]

**Individualsheets after insert**

[image: Individualsheets- Apple]
[image: Individualsheets- Soft Drinks]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) for reading/writing Excel spreadsheets.

```
Using package As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage(New FileInfo("c:\temp\file.xlsx"))
    Dim sheet As ExcelWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("New worksheet")
    sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Hello world!"
    package.Save()
End Using
```